# How to search $_POST for dynamic added input values?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, post, search

I have a form where i add inputs on the fly.

The names of the inputs start the same but has a number added on the end:
`<input type="number" name="number_of_floors_house_'+i+'">`

Now, when i post my form i would like to loop threw this inputs.

So i need something like `array_search($_POST['number_of_floors_house_%']`

Or find all $*POST['keys'] that starts with 'number_of_floors_house*' and loop them threw to get it's values :)

Can you help please?

**EDIT**
I've tried:

```
$houses_and_floors = array_search('number_of_floors_house_%', $_POST);
var_dump($houses_and_floors);
```

Comment: So which did you try? The second look like a simple foreach loop to build a new array of "Stuff I want" dont you think

Comment: Just have a look at the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your input to something like this:

```
<input type="number" name="number_of_floors['+i+']">
```

The square brackets make the input submit as an array, so you could then loop through all the values easier:

```
foreach($_POST['number_of_floors'] as $house_number => $value) {
    // $house_number will be whatever number was added to the form element.
    // $value is the actual input boxes value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `array_filter()` to pick out the pieces of $_POST you actually want like this

```
//fake up a post array
$_POST = ['aa'=>1, 'bb'=>2, 'number_of_floors_house_1'=>2, 'number_of_floors_house_2'=>2,'number_of_floors_house_3'=>4];

function picker($v, $k)
{
    return strpos($k, 'number_of_floors_house') !== FALSE;
}
$res = array_filter($_POST, 'picker', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
print_r($res);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [number_of_floors_house_1] => 2
    [number_of_floors_house_2] => 2
    [number_of_floors_house_3] => 4
)
```

Comment: While `strpos` will work for this case, wouldn't it be safer to do an explicit prefix comparison? Suppose the form also included keys like `number_of_floors_housework` or `view_number_of_floors_house`, we'd have false positives.

Comment: Also, why do you return a key-value pair from the `array_filter` callback? "*If the callback function returns TRUE, the current value from array is returned into the result array." (Manual)* It seems that simply `return strpos(...` would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter for array keys matching a given prefix with [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`strncmp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php):

```
$prefix = 'number_of_floors_';
$length = strlen($prefix);

$nof = array_filter($_POST, function($key) use ($prefix, $length) {
    return strncmp($prefix, $key, $length) === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

This will filter your post data for all array members with the defined prefix. Note that we're checking the prefix length outside the function to avoid a redundant repeated evaluation inside the function (which is executed for once each array member). You could, of course, also just hard-code this for a single use-case and skip the leading variables above:

```
$nof = array_filter($_POST, function($key) {
    return strncmp('number_of_floors_', $key, 17) === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

...which would compare the first 17 characters of each key with the defined string. Again, you could also do this with `substr()` in place of `strncmp()`, with `return substr($key, 0, $length) === $prefix` as the filter condition. I chose the former for this example, since it's a function explicitly for the "*binary safe string comparison of the first n characters*".